# Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot Unable to find element after jQuery slider ran

Tags: jquery, reactjs, slick.js

I have a React application that renders a jQuery slick slider which all goes well, but when I go to the next state this slider isn't there anymore and React throws a Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot.

In short what's going on:

```
renderIntro: function () {

    return <section className="content__wrap text-center questionnaire__intro">
        <div className="introSlider">
            <div className="slide">
                <h2>Welcome!</h2>
                <p>For this event we need you to answer some questions</p>
            </div>
            <div className="slide">
                <h2>How</h2>
                <p>We'll show you a question with two pictures</p>
                <p>Tap on the picture of your choice</p>
            </div>
            <div className="slide">
                <h2>Okay!</h2>
                <p>When you're ready, click the start button below</p>
                <div onClick={this.startQuestionnaire} className="button button--primary">Start</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
},

startIntroSlider: function() {
    if ( $('.introSlider' ).length > 0 ) {
        $('.introSlider').slick({
            infinite: false,
            dots: true
        });
        if(this.state.questionnaireStarted) {
            $('.introSlider').unslick();
        }
    }
},

componentDidUpdate: function () {
},

componentDidMount: function () {
    this.startIntroSlider();
},

render: function ()
{
    var renderMain = this.renderQuestions();
    if ( !this.state.questionnaire.started ) {
        renderMain = this.renderIntro();
    }

    return <div className="wrapper wrapper--questionnaire">
        <div className={"l-container l-container--mobile " + this.state.questionnaire.questionnaire.class}>
            {renderMain}
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

If questions are started render those, otherwise render the intro which is a slider. The last slide contains a button to start the questions after which the slider isn't in DOM anymore.

I can't think about how to do this differently as I'm really new to React so I would love some help :)!

Comment: This does not answer your question so I'm adding as a comment. Mixing React with jQuery is not a good practice since React works with virtual DOM. There is a react version of the Slick slider. You can check it out. https://github.com/akiran/react-slick

Comment: Sadly the application is not developed by me and they have integrated jQuery very heavily in it. Besides I have no React experience so it's all really difficult to achieve in my case. I tried the React Slick component except jQuery isnt loaded as a node module so the React Slick component won't run because it thinks jQuery isn't available.